# Alternative to jQuery ui sortable needed

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to use jQuery ui sortable but it's not working out for me, it's having scroll offset issues when scrolled in Firefox. The goal is to have a list of `<li>` tags that a user can re-order with their mouse.

My question is, what alternatives exist for that plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after searching around for a while, I found this one by Interface Elements, which has almost identical utility and doesn't have the same issues with Firefox.

- http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/sort
- http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/sort_lists.html

Comment: Interface Elements looks like it may be an early version of jQuery UI. The most recent version is from 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you are the man! This has been driving me nuts for about 2 hours now.

Apparently the problem is caused by having html overflow-y set to scroll. Although it stick doesn't work for me a lot of the time when elements have padding. It's infuriating.

EDIT: Bugger. Interface is no longer supported, and bugs out with the later versions of jQuery.

EDIT2: OK, so you can solve all the bugs with jQuery sortable by doing these 2 things:

1 - make sure the html elements does have overflow-y:scroll

2 - ensure that none of the parent elements to the sortable have position:relative

I am now using the latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI and all is good (but I have no idea why they don't TELL you on the same page, or have a "Bugs" tab. Dumb)

Comment: How come? I'm trying to sort some UL inside relative divs with overflow:auto (which means scroll!). All due to the fact the number of li elements can be large enough... I guess my approach no longer works in FF (tried in opera and it works!) :-/

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, but I landed here from Google, so here's a nice library that might do the job - DragonflyJS:

https://getbutterfly.com/dragonflyjs-vanilla-javascript-drag-and-drop/

It's only 300+ lines and seems to work on all modern browsers.